# Backup_Migrate Module able to Create Backups but NOT Restore them

Tags: backups, files

- Using Drupal 7.37, Omega4-SubTheme
- Acquia Dev-Desktop Stack (Development)
- Windows 7 HP
- Using Backup_Migrate-3.1.

1. I set up my Backup and Migrate settings to back up my entire website-code and the corresponding Database.
2. This is set to copy the Backup to a subfolder in my C:\ Folder directory.
3. Back up and Migrate saves the Backups fine and I can see them when I navigate to my Backup-Folder.
4. They are saved as Zipped-Files.
5. If I try to restore using one of my Backups, I get an error (next item).
6. Exception: Unable to create directory 'C:\Drupal-Temporary/backup_migrate_556bb93614fe3/docroot/C:' in Archive_Tar->_error() (line 635 of C:\Users\Chandra Swa\Sites\drupal-7\modules\system\system.tar.inc).
7. There appears to be some problem in reading a "Temporary" directory, not my actual saved Backup directory.
8. What is causing this error; what does it even mean; is there a fix?

Thank you for your time to read this.  I have tried to be as thorough as possible.

Comment: I don't do windows, so I may be wrong about this, but this filename:      `C:\Drupal-Temporary/backup_migrate_556bb93614fe3/docroot/C:` look fubared.  I don't think the `C:` at the end belong there.  If that is the cause, you still need to figure out why it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the Patch mentioned on following URL:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2320969#comment-9564267

Patch for make full site restore (and full site backup) work on Windows. The main 
problem was in assumption that directory separator is always '/' but that's not true on Win. So wherever i've found '/' in operation on paths i've changed them to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly do you apply this fix? I am lost in this area of Drupal could you kindly give me a step-by-step.

Comment: I saw a Video on YouTube describing this process.  I can see why no has answered.  Yet another side-technology to grapple through.  Live and learn.

Comment: Again after a closer look, I see that the Video is describing applying a patch in the Production-Environment in Linux and I am in a Development-Environment on Windows.  Any clues as to how make the necessary adjustment here?